# Filter specific HTTP verbs in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm getting a lot of errors in my spring MVC app caused by some clients requesting HTTP PROPFIND:

16:59:39,402 ERROR [foo.bar.controllers.ExceptionHandlingController] (default task-12) Uncaught Error: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PROPFIND' not supported

How can I filter this requests so that they don't generate an error in each controller ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring's HandlerInterceptor as below to allow & process the required requests.

**RequestMethodInterceptor class:**

```
package com.myproject.RequestMethodInterceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RequestMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //Added PROPFIND method, add any other types NOT allowed
        if(request.getMethod().equals("PROPFIND") ) {
            //Log or Ignore upon your requirement & return false
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

**XML Configuration:**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
      <bean class="com.myproject.RequestMethodInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: And when another unknown method is sent, they have to change their code. A whitelist is preferable, don't you think?

Comment: yes, you are right, we can create a whitelist and validate

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the spring `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` in managing OPTIONS
In the web.xml you should add something like this

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: What exactly does `OPTIONS` have to do with `PROPFIND`?

Comment: I saw on spring documentation and old forum that it's necessary to enable options; I never tried it but if spring say so i do believe it

Comment: _"it's necessary to enable options"_ But OP's question is not about OPTIONS. More importantly: The OP does NOT want to handle the requests. They want to discard the request.